# Removing words in text files containing a character or string of letters with Python

Tags: python, string, nlp, special-characters, corpus

I have a few lines of text and want to remove any word with special characters or a fixed given string in them (in python).

Example:

```
in_lines = ['this is go:od', 
            'that example is bad', 
            'amp is a word']

# remove any word with {'amp', ':'}
out_lines = ['this is', 
             'that is bad', 
             'is a word']
```

I know how to remove words from a list that is given but cannot remove words with special characters or few letters being present. Please let me know and I'll add more information.

This is what I have for removing selected words:

```
def remove_stop_words(lines):
   stop_words = ['am', 'is', 'are']
   results = []
   for text in lines:
        tmp = text.split(' ')
        for stop_word in stop_words:
            for x in range(0, len(tmp)):
               if tmp[x] == stop_word:
                  tmp[x] = ''
        results.append(" ".join(tmp))
   return results
out_lines = remove_stop_words(in_lines)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
in_lines = ['this is go:od', 
            'that example is bad', 
            'amp is a word']

def remove_words(in_list, bad_list):
    out_list = []
    for line in in_list:
        words = ' '.join([word for word in line.split() if not any([phrase in word for phrase in bad_list]) ])
        out_list.append(words)
    return out_list

out_lines = remove_words(in_lines, ['amp', ':'])
print (out_lines)
```

Strange as it sounds, the statement

```
word for word in line.split() if not any([phrase in word for phrase in bad_list])
```

does all the hard work here at once. It creates a list of `True`/`False` values for each phrase in the "bad" list applied to a single word. The `any` function condenses this temporary list into a single `True`/`False` value again, and if this is `False` then the word can safely be copied into the line-based output list.

As an example, the result of removing all words containing an `a` looks like this:

```
remove_words(in_lines, ['a'])
>>> ['this is go:od', 'is', 'is word']
```

(It is possible to remove the `for line in ..` line as well. At that point, readability *really* starts to suffer, though.)

Comment: Thank you @usr2564301 This is an exact match.

Answer (score 1):

This matches your expected output:

```
def remove_stop_words(lines):
  stop_words = ['am', ':']
  results = []
  for text in lines:
    tmp = text.split(' ')
    for x in range(0, len(tmp)):
      for st_w in stop_words:
        if st_w in tmp[x]:
          tmp[x] = ''
    results.append(" ".join(tmp))
  return results
```